# Facing image uploading error in interventoin / laravel 4.2

Tags: php, git, bash, laravel, intervention

Facing some problem when uploading image using Intervention service provider on laravel 4.2

error- Can't write image data to path.

-searched on google and stackoverflow and tried to solve but the problem is still unsolved. may that directory has not in writable mod. how can I make the diretory 'public/img/products/' writable mod in windows 7 using git bash and Cygwin Terminal too

my product controller create method -

```
public function postCreate() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Product::$rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->category_id = Input::get('category_id');
        $product->title = Input::get('title');
        $product->description = Input::get('description');
        $product->price = Input::get('price');

        $image = Input::file('image');
        $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')."-".$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = public_path('img/products/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save($path);
        $product->image = 'img/products/';
        $product->save();

        return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
            ->with('message', 'Product Created');
    }

    return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though this is an old thread.
Windows file name must not have ":"(colon) as a character. Instead use "-"(dash) or "_"(underscore). Even a space(" ") will be fine. 
Example:

```
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H_i_s')."-".$image->getClientOriginalName();
```

or

```
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H i s')."-".$image->getClientOriginalName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the access permissions of directory.

`sudo chmod -R 777 public/img/products`

Comment: but i am using git bash on windows7, gave that command but it seems  that, directory is still not writable